# Close console app after calling webapi without waiting for result

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to call a webapi from a console application (which is triggered by windows task scheduler). I don't want my console app to wait for the result from api.I just want to call api and initiate it and exit the console application.

My console application code is

```
public static void InvokeSisService(string feature)
        {
            var serviceurl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppServiceURL"];
            var controllerPath= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ControllerPath"];

            var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(serviceurl) };

            controllerPath= controllerPath+ "?feature=" + feature;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


            //client.PostAsync(smsservicepath, null);
           // var temp=client.GetAsync(smsservicepath).Result;
            var response = Task.Run(() => client.GetAsync(controllerPath)).Result;
}
```

My webapi is being called but it was waiting for the output.How do i exit console app after calling api.

Webapi code

```
  [HttpGet]
    [Route("ProcessService")]
    public HttpResponseMessage ProcessService([FromUri] string feature)
    {
    }
```

Comment: You can read this article http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html from Stephen Cleary

Comment: Good article, but it is about fire and forget from the server, not the client.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you want to make sure the response was received, so change

```
  var response = Task.Run(() => client.GetAsync(controllerPath)).Result;
```

To:

```
  using (var response = await client.GetAsync(controllerPath, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
```

This will drop after the response headers have been received. This does NOT include error handling - you should probably add error handling to the mix to make sure you are getting a proper response code before moving on - but that's up to you.

Comment: FYI, i dont want to catch the response from the API...i want to simply call and exit my program.

Comment: Then take out the await and be gone!

Answer (score 0):

> var response = Task.Run(() =>
>   client.GetAsync(controllerPath)).Result;

with the property "Result" you are waiting for the Response.